# How to add a specific number of labels to a label array?

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach, label

I've been trying to add a few candles to an array so I can use that array for the rest of my code, using the candles' properties more easily. However it doesn't seem as my code is correct and I would love someone to help me with this. (Color != DarkGoldenrod differentiates the candles from the other labels in my project, all of which have the same color)

```
private Label[] CandlesToMatrix()
    {
        Label[] candles = new Label[7];
        foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
        {
            if ((ctrl is Label) && (ctrl.BackColor != Color.DarkGoldenrod))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
                {
                    candles[i] = (Label)ctrl;
                }
            }
        }
        return candles;

    }
```

Comment: Please explain in steps (pseudo code) what you would like to achieve

Comment: @Simon I would like to insert 7 specific labels into a label array (search for them automatically)

Comment: you are filling the whole array with the last control which matches the criteria. You should not use a for loop for this. And why the number 7?

Comment: In your code candles[i] = (Label)ctrl creates 7 identical labels in candles

Comment: I think you need candles[i] = (Label)ctrl[i];

Comment: How do I fix it? I am new to foreach

Comment: try Replace candles[i] = (Label)ctrl with 
candles[i] = ctrl[i];

Comment: @Simon it says "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Control'"

Comment: How do I make ctrl into a Label

Comment: candles[i] = (Label)ctrl[i];

Comment: Add code of ctrl assignment, is it even an array?

Comment: @Simon candles is the array, ctrl is the label that needs to keep changing in order to get in the array

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen How do I scroll through the array replacing each place there with a label without a for loop?

Comment: @FogelF7 I just wrote an answer for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that you assign each element in the array the control that matches the criteria.

The code runs like: Enumerate all controls and check if it is a label and not some specific color. If he finds one, he will fill up the whole array with a reference to that control. If the array was already filled by the previous match, it will be overwritten.

So you end up with an array filled with either a null or the last matching control.

I think you would like to have the array filled with 'unique' controls. So every time you find a match, you have to increase the index to write it to.

For example:

```
private Label[] CandlesToMatrix()
{
    Label[] candles = new Label[7];

    // declare a variable to keep hold of the index
    int currentIndex = 0;

    foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
    {
        if ((ctrl is Label label) && (label.BackColor != Color.DarkGoldenrod))
        {
            // check if the currentIndex is within the array. Never read/write outside the array.
            if(currentIndex == candles.Length)
                break;
                
            candles[currentIndex] = label;
            currentIndex++;
        }
    }
}
```

I'll add another example......

C# has so much more to offer. This is a little old c programming style. Fixed size arrays etc. In C# you have also a List which uses the type you use between the `<` and `>`. For example. `List<Label>`.

Here is an example which uses a List.

```
private Label[] CandlesToMatrix()
{
    List<Label> candles = new List<Label>();
    
    // int currentIndex = 0;   You don't need to keep track of the index. Just add it.
    foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
    {
        if ((ctrl is Label label) && (label.BackColor != Color.DarkGoldenrod))
        {
            candles.Add(label);
        }
    }
    
    return candles.ToArray(); // if you still want the array as result.
}
```

and... you could also use Linq (which is a next step)

```
private Label[] CandlesToMatrix()
{
    return this.Controls
        // check the type.
        .OfType<Label>()
        // matches it the creteria?
        .Where(label => ((ctrl is Label label) && (label.BackColor != Color.DarkGoldenrod))
        // fillup an array with the results
        .ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works, I am having another problem now with somewhere else in the code but this part has been solved so thank you!